# How can to generate error for testing exception in unit test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have same code:

```
def foo(self):
  x = self.a + self.b
  try:
    res = self.a / self.b
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    res = foo_2()
  except AttributeError:
    res = foo_3()
  except CustomError:
    res = foo_4()
  except RemoteAPIError:
    res = foo_5()
  return res

def foo_2():
  ...

def foo_3():
  ...

def foo_4():
  ...

def foo_5():
  ...
```

How can to raise `ZeroDivisionError`, `AttributeError` etc in `unittest` or `mock`?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Are you merely asking how to raise an exception, e.g. `raise ValueError`? Or are you asking how to force the `foo` function to run the branches associated with those errors?

Comment: `how to force the foo function to run the branches associated with those errors`

Comment: In that case, have your tried, e.g., setting `self.b` to `0`, removing the attribute `self.a`?

Comment: @Brian I need to somehow generate errors *without manipulating attributes*. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you reset the values of a and b within your test? `object.b = 0` and then write the rest of your test

Comment: @mattyx17 I can't to do it

Comment: Hmm ... This isn't a great solution but maybe you can make the part that calculates `res` a separate function and the mock that function to throw each error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `object` is an instance of your class such that object.b = 0 then you can do this

```
   import pytest
   from unittest.mock import MagicMock

   object.foo_2 = MagicMock() 
   with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
       object.foo()
   object.foo_2.assert_called_once()
```

Similarly, you can create instances of your class that generate the other two errors

Comment: `DID NOT RAISE <class 'stripe.error.APIConnectionError>`

Comment: Yeah, I did not realize you can't set the object's attributes. I think in that case the easiest is to make `res = self.a / self.b` into a separate function and then mock that function to throw each of the errors